# IntelliJ Running other class files, how do I stop this?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-15

[image]

Why this other class file is running instead of the one I clicked on please help. My Process is included in the gif, I can't tell why this is occurring.

Comment: It's not running it, it's compiling it and the whole application must compile before you can run tests.

Comment: Must I remove the other folders / work files ? & Upon doing so I got this error : objc[3605]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1051c24c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10528c4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: It sounds like a bit of a mess. I don't have enough info to help, my best advice would be to go back to the last working version and go forward from there.

Comment: What did you use to make the gif by the way?

Comment: ScreenFlow , and so its a jdk problem ? apart from the broken class file ?

Comment: I never said that it's a JDK problem. It's definitely your problem. Don't ignore the errors. They tell you the exact problem. Method `CostPanel` has no return type. But I think you copied and renamed a class without renaming its constructor.

Comment: I deleated those files to get rid of the problem but i was talking about this:                                                                                                   
objc[3605]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/‌​Home/bin/java (0x1051c24c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/‌​Home/jre/lib/libinst‌​rument.dylib (0x10528c4e0)

Comment: This has gone beyond your original question. Each time you fix one problem and get another, always go back to google,  you're very unlikely to be the first one to have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because before running the test class, the IDE needs to build the project, it found a class that has error and can not complete the test. You can try to fix the `ButtonPanel.java` class and try to run the test again

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with it, as it is a default exercise filed untouched...

Comment: In the line 19 from `ButtonPanel` class is missing the return type in the `CostPanel` method

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Don't click on the run button. Right click on the class you want to run and click run.

Answer (score 0):

It's not running it, it's compiling it and the whole application must compile before you can run tests. You must fix the errors to continue.

Don't ignore the errors. They tell you the exact problem. Method `CostPanel` has no return type. But I think you copied and renamed a class without renaming its constructor.